# First eigenfunction of laplacian has minimum in compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: laplacian, eigenfunctions

I encountered a problem which leads to prove $\frac{1}{\left | \varphi _{1}(x) \right |}$ is a bounded function, $ \varphi _{1}$ is the first eigenfunction of laplacian in an open, bounded, smooth domain in  $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely $\Omega$.
Since the closure of  $\Omega$ is compact, I'm hoping on the continuity of $ \varphi _{1}$. But I'm not sure if $ \varphi _{1}$ is in the class $C^1(\overline{\Omega} )$?

If possible please give me some book titles or lecture notes about this aspect (I'm a beginner).

Thank you.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions? For Dirichlet boundary conditons this is false already in 1-D, while it's obviously true for Neumann boundary conditions

Comment: @HansEngler I got Dirichlet BC on my problem, so continuity is a wrong approach. Can you suggest me some other ways to prove the boundedness? I'm stuck there.

Comment: In a bounded domain with smooth boundary, the first eigenfunction satisfies $\varphi_1(x) \sim (dist(x,\partial \Omega))$ near the boundary, so $\frac{1}{|\varphi_1(x)|}$ is unbounded. Example: $\Omega = (0,\pi) \subset \mathbb{R}, \varphi_1(x) = \sin x$.